# Grails: Function located in a rendered template cannot be run from index page

Tags: html, grails

I have an index, in my index, I am rendering a template called dateFilter.gsp

index.gsp

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
//$('#dateFilter').val("This Year").trigger("change");
});
</script>
```

dateFilter.gsp

```
<g:select id="dateFilter" from="${["Today", "This Week", "This Month", "Last Month", "This Year", "This Fiscal Year"]}"                                  noSelection="${['null':'Custom']}" value="${params.dateFilter}"                                 
class="commonSelectSize3Cols"/>

<button class="applyButton" id="applyButton">Apply</button>

<script>
$("#dateFilter").on("change",function(){
alert("Date changed!");
});

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#dateFilter').val("This Year").trigger("change");
});
</script
```

when I put this code

> $('#dateFilter').val("This Year").trigger("change");

inside the **$(document).ready** of **dateFilter.gsp**, the code works properly, meaning, the selected option is changed to "This Year" and the onChange event is run. But, If I placed the code that triggers the change in select box inside the **$(document).ready** of **index**, the code successfully set the selected option to this year but onChange event function is not run. I even tried to check if the dateFilter element can be seen from index, yes it is.

But why can't it run the onChange event function from index? And if there's a workaround for this, what is it? Thanks.

Comment: Unsure of why it would cause an issue. As a test try onchange="alert ('hello');" inside g:select tag

Comment: @vahid I did what you said and it run. Weird. Normally, in situation's like this, is it really possible to run a function located in a template from index or a page where it is rendered? If your answer is yes, then there's probably something wrong with my code. Thanks

Comment: Well it maybe that you have not declared the g:select properly in the first instance. When you define a grails form field usually it has a name="fieldName" in your case you don't seem to have a form name declaration. When you set the name value, grails by default then assigns the id value of this to be the same as the name so try everything the same but change id="dateFilter" to name="dateFilter" and see if the javascript then picks it up. It may be that you need to declare it outside of the document.ready function for it to work